# Need help fixing expensive website template

Tags: html, css, templates

I bought this website template from dreamtemplate and the copyright text displays on the center of the page ontop of the main body content! I had not changed any code at all. It was like that when I extracted the files. I looked at the code and couldn't find anything wrong, but I guess that doesn't say much since I had to buy a template :P

Here's a screenshot of it:

http://jt-software.net/baddesign.png

The html for that page is at:
http://jt-software.net/services.html

And the css styling is at:
http://jt-software.net/style.css

Can someone please help me fix this? :)

Thank you

Comment: Maybe you should demand your money back?

Comment: If you paid money for the template I would either (a) request that the author fixes the problem or (b) demand a refund!

Comment: I wasn't aware SO was the new RentACoderForFree.com. Ask for a refund, get the original developer to fix it or hire someone to do this for you.

Comment: Hmmm. It seems that I've offended some people. That wasn't my intention. You're right, I could ask for a refund. But have emailed them, but have had no reply. And it's been over a week now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try in *style.css* on line 7, for `.header_resize` change `height:490px` to `min-height:490px`

Comment: Brilliant! Thank you very very much dragosplesca :) If I wasn't strapped for cash I'd hire you on the spot!